# grok regular expression is not working in log stash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, grok

I'm a total newbie and I have created this filter in Logstash and the purpose is to create a "tag" in Elasticsearch called CVE that will find CVE numbers like CVE-1000-1000 or CVE-2016-0505 or any other 4 digit abritary number.

My code looks like this:

```
filter { 
    grok {
        match => [
            "CVE",
            "(CVE-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4})"
        ]
    }
}
```

I also wonder how i can make it case insensitive.

Please help!

Comment: Could you add an example of the line you wish to parse? Also: [grok documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html)

Comment: Hello I'm monitoring a Twitter feed and the CVE numbers could exist in any arbitrary text. I want to monitor and visualize  in Kibana based on information that people have Twittered about CVE numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution

```
grok {
    match => ["text", "(?<cve>CVE-\d{4}-\d{4})"]
}
```

Big thanks to Magnus Bäck at Elastic